# C# - Proper way to run sequential tasks?

Tags: c#

New to C# and learning as i go. I've tried Googling, but havent found what im looking for (still looking).
I have a simple C# App that so far is working fine. The next part i want to figure out is how to invoke a series of tasks/methods.

Say i have 4 individual tasks (Tasks 1-4). Each one of them does something different...

Button 1 - Shows a Messagebox
Button 2 - Changes a label text color
Button 3 - Writes something to console.
etc
etc.

Each one of these works fine when you press its associated button. But now lets say i have a Checkbox next to each of these that you can check/uncheck. Plus a button that says "run selected".

My question is how do i program that button to run ALL the tasks in sequential order AND only run the tasks that are selected?

Checkbox 1 - OFF
Checkbox 2 - ON
Checkbox 3 - OFF
Checkbox 4 - ON

So when i press the "Run Selected" Button - Only Tasks 2 and 4 run.

Again, im new, and my lingo may not be correct - but hopefully you get the idea.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: `if (checkBox1.Checked) { button1.PerformClick(); } if (checkBox2.Checked) { button2.PerformClick(); } ...` and so on. Alternatively, you could move the code for each `ButtonX_Click` event handler to a separate method, call that method in the event handler and then call the corresponding method instead of `buttonX.PerformClick();` in the code above.

Comment: Search for "task continuation" and "ContinueWith".

Comment: @StackOverthrow I don't think the OP means that kind of `Task`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I would isolate each task outside the click handlers of the buttons, into its own methods:

```
private void Task1()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Task 1");
}
private void Task2()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Task 2");
}
private void Task3()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Task 3");
}
private void Task4()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Task 4");
}
```

I just used simple message boxes for the sake of simplicity, but any code will work actually.

Then make each click handler just call each method:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Task1();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Task2();
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Task3();
}

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Task4();
}
```

Now the important part, when the "do all checked" button is clicked, you check each checkbox state and launch the appropriate method in sequence:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.checkBox1.Checked) this.Task1();
    if (this.checkBox2.Checked) this.Task2();
    if (this.checkBox3.Checked) this.Task3();
    if (this.checkBox4.Checked) this.Task4();
}
```

Comment: OK! Thank you for this! Ill give this a shot right now! :)

Comment: Working great! Thank you! :)

Comment: this doesn't guarantee sequential execution if the OP is use async events

Comment: @johnny5 Sure, but nothing in the question indicates the OP is using anything `async` or `await` or `Task`. But if that were the case, making the event handler `async` and `await`ing each call would suffice to ensure sequencial execution, and maybe disable the button to prevent reentry.